# Jigsaw Probability

Tags: probability

I have a jigsaw puzzle with 250 jigsaw pieces. What is the probability that if I pick 2 pieces they are adjacent joining pieces?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This depends slightly on the shape of the puzzle. Could you say how many rows and columns there are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We pick two pieces.

If the first piece has four adjacent pieces, then the second piece is adjacent to the first with probability $4/249$.
If the first piece has three adjacent pieces (i.e. was on the border but was not a corner), then the second piece is adjacent to the first with probability $3/249$.
If the first piece has two adjacent pieces (i.e. was a corner), then the second piece is adjacent to the first with probability $2/249$.
If the first piece has a single adjacent piece (in the case for endpieces if the puzzle is laid out as a line), then the second piece is adjacent to the first with probability $1/249$.

The exact probability is thus
$\Pr(\text{two pieces fit}) = (n_4/250)(4/249) + (n_3/250)(3/249) + (n_2/250)(2/249)$,
where $n_i$ is the number of pieces with $i$ adjacent pieces. Thus this depends on the layout of the puzzle.

Comment: Or, more specifically, it depends on the number of pieces that are an edge piece.